# I’m trying to transfer BTC from Bitcoin.com to Coinbase and I keep getting a message that says could not broadcast payment. What does that mean?

Tags: broadcast

I am trying to transfer BTC from Bitcoin.com to Coinbase.  I keep getting a message that says “Could not broadcast payment”.  What does that mean? I’ve tried 50.00 and 500.00.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://forum.bitcoin.com/beginners-help/bch-wallet-error-t62091.html

> This error basically means that your wallet is unable to connect with the Bitcoin.com wallet server.
> When we see a few of these error come in to support then it is normally a problem at our end and will often be fixed within a couple of hours. If you have been seeing this same error for 10+ days then i would guess that the problem is at your end.
> Please check to make sure you have good internet connection and try again.
>
> Please email support if the problem is still occurring and give as much information as possible, including screenshots.
>
> wallet@bitcoin.com

I've no idea why that company's wallet app needs to contact their server if it is self-custodial as claimed.

Comment: lol, 10 days to fix problems?